# jQuery Reseting a position after animation

Tags: jquery, positioning

I'm trying to reset the CSS position of an element after it's been animated, but failing.

I've tried using stop(), queue:false, and specifying the css position to use after the animation is complete but none of these methods are working. Can anyone help?

I've simplified my code and posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/DSs6r/

Rapidly move your mouse in and out of the red block and you'll see that things queue up after a while and the position of top: 0px; is not maintained.

Comment: Your `.css('top', '')` bits are happening before the animations, is that the intention?  Does that restore it to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want you can specify the exact values to change top to instead of += and -=

http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/DSs6r/2/

I'm not sure if this helps you for whatever you're using this for though.

Comment: Excellent Paul, I didn't think about this, but it seems obvious now. Solves it :-)