# jQuery Element position is reset after show and stop animation

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery

I position an element using jQuery .position(). However after I show an animation and cancel it after an ajax call the position of the element gets reset.

```
function showStatusMsg(msg) {
    var $statusEl = $('#userActMenuStatus');

    if ($statusEl.length == 0) {
        $statusEl = $('<span id="userActMenuStatus">' + msg + '</span>');

        $('#app_nav').append($statusEl);
        $statusEl.position({
            my: "right center",
            at: "left center",
            of: $('#userActMenu'),
            collision: "fit"
        }).css('left', parseInt($statusEl.css('left')) - 10);

    } else {
        $statusEl.html(msg);
    }

}

$('#button1').click(function () {
    showStatusMsg('saving...');
    $('#userActMenuStatus').stop(true).show('drop', {
        direction: 'up'
    }, 'slow').effect('pulsate', {
        'times': 100
    }, 1500);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: 'save=data'
    }).success(function (result) {
        $('#userActMenuStatus').stop(true).hide('drop', {
            direction: 'up'
        }, 'slow');

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NhdgM/2/

What is going on?

Disclaimer: I have to use  jQuery v1.5.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI's `.show()` and `.hide()` are setting the left CSS value at times and messes up the positioning. I stumbled across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6727546/809217) which suggested to just use `.animate()` and set the top CSS value explicitly for the animations. This fixed the problem.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NhdgM/5/)

Answer (score 0):

how are you expecting `position` to behave? http://api.jquery.com/position/
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js#L90

It looks like just a reader to me.

Comment: I need the element to be positioned alongside another dynamically sized element. I can't hardcode it since the size changes.

Comment: you're not using ```$.position()``` correctly. It's for reading values, not setting.

Comment: It looks like you're referring to jQuery-ui's ```position()``` http://api.jqueryui.com/position/